# html5 database skipping transactions and mixing up transactions?

Tags: javascript, database, html

This has been driving me nuts for days! There must be something I'm missing about the asynchronous nature of html5 database transactions.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/zE7bX/18/

In my code, I'm creating three tables and populating them with data. At the end, I end up with 3 tables but the first two don't get populated with data. And in the third table, for some reason, it ends up getting populated with the data meant for table 2 and table 3. I think this is because all tables are being populated using the same function so they're clashing somehow.

Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: I'm doing some more testing and I think it has to do with variable scope. I'm putting "vars" in front of local variables and that seems to solve some issues.